# How to adjust the buffersize of a CaptureSource in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, buffer, microphone

I'm writing a voicechat based on silverlight. Therefore I use a `CaptureSource` to reach the audioinput (microphone). This puts its data through a `Sink`, from which I can get the recorded raw sample data. What I have noticed is that I always get the data for about 0,5 seconds. This is really bad for realtime streaming and would result in a noticeable delay.

So my question is, whether there is any option to adjust the size of the buffered amount of samples, so that I get a smaller count of samples from my `Sink`, by not touching the sample rate of the input device?